# js code including linked files, within html file, works. move it out and it gives errors

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

The following code (adapted from [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/indicators/ema/) pointed to from [highcharts.com](https://highcharts.com) documentation) works great all in one html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
        <script>
            const oOptionsBase = {
                    rangeSelector: { selected: 1 },
                    title: { text: 'AAPL Stock Price' },
                    series: [{
                        type: 'candlestick',
                        name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
                        data: {},
                    }]
                }
                function drawChart(data) {
                    const oOptions = oOptionsBase;
                    oOptions.series[0].data = data;
                    Highcharts.stockChart('container', oOptions);
                }
                const sUrlJsonDataSrc = 'https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-ohlc.json'
                Highcharts.getJSON(sUrlJsonDataSrc, drawChart);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">Hold please...</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Next, I move all the code between the last  tag pair to another file, `main.js`, and instead add above:

`<script src="main.js"></script>`

Everything then still works, however, my IDE (VS Code) gives me an error that Highcharts is undefined.  This error makes sense to me because from the perspective of this JS file it can't see it.  Only the html file can. (...right?)

That said, I'd like to remove all the highcharts script links/tags and have the main.js file as the ONLY thing that can see the highcharts library.

But I can't seem to find any way to do that.  Is it is possible?  Is it sensible?  If I can't or shouldn't do that, is there something I can at least do to not have my main.js scattered with `... is undefined` errors?

How do I link/get to those files (or equivalent downloaded copies of them, or npm versions of them) from the separate JS file, or what else do I have to do, to have that JS file understand what the Highcharts object is?

(PS. The above is a simplified sample of my problem.  The actual problem is a lot more code, but I've stripped down just to the essence for the question).

Comment: You can do that by setting up a bundler (webpack, vite, rollup, etc.) to build your js files. Then you can `npm install --save highcharts` and in your main.js `import Highcharts from 'highcharts';`

Comment: Hi @DavidT, Please check Highcharts documentation about installation: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/installation and readme on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts Basically, as the above comment suggests, you can use bundler, import and initialize Highcharts with modules.

Comment: So are those bundlers the only way to address/do this?  I did try the npm route and I couldn't get that to work.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: No, it's not the only way, but probably the most universal one. First of all, scripts are run in order, so they can depend on each other. `Highcharts` should be defined in your `main` script, so maybe the script order or config of your code editor is wrong. You can also get the required code (useful link: https://code.highcharts.com/) and manually add it to the main script, for example http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xch2yzLt/

Comment: @ppotaczek Ok. thanks for the explanation.  Sounds like my VSCode isn't set up right, since I believe I've done everything you said there.  I'll pursue that and see if that sorts me out.  Thanks for the help!